# How to put correct attribute '@id' value based on the '@rid' value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to put correct value in the attribute `@id` based on the `@rid` attribute value.
**Logic:** If element `a` more then `1` and element `cu` equal to `1` in the 'au' element than how to add position  after the attribute value e.g `(<a id="a">...</a>, <a id="a">...</a>)` s/b `(<a id="a1">...</a>, <a id="a2">...</a>)`
How to solve this issue template match only `a` element.
Please check Expecting Output:

**Input:**

```
<root>
<t>Title</t>
<au>
    <cu>
        <x rid="a1 a2"/>
    </cu>
</au>
<a id="a">Centre</a>
<a id="a">Westmead</a>
<n>notes</n>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code:**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:if test="count(../a) &gt; 1 and count(../au/cu[x]) = 1 and @id">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="self::node()" group-adjacent="self::a">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('a',$pos)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            <!--</xsl:for-each>-->
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expecting Output:**

```
<root>
<t>Title</t>
<au>
    <cu>
        <x rid="a1 a2"/>
    </cu>
</au>
<a id="a1">Centre</a>
<a id="a2">Westmead</a>
<n>notes</n>
```

Comment: Please explain the required logic in words.

Comment: Sorry, it's too confusing - esp. since you have the values `a1 a2` in the input.

Comment: Input @id value is `a` expecting is `a1` if element `a` is more than `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it from the template for `a` use

```
  <xsl:template match="root[a[2] and not(au/cu[x][2])]/a[@id]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">a<xsl:number/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: And how is this "based on the '@rid' value"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, good point in reference to some of the criteria mentioned in the question title but in the end I couldn't find any of that in the samples, there it seems the generation of  `a` with `id` attributes `a1`, `a2`, .. was all that appeared to happen so my attempt at an answer to do that with a template for `a` is above. Feel free to write some where `a/@id` is "based" on `@rid` if you have grasped what that is meant to say.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry, I should have made it clear my comment was addressed to the OP. And it's not really a question, merely an expression of frustration. Evidently you managed to grasp what OP meant to say - but it surely couldn't be concluded from what they did say.